# ffmpeg: add album art with fluent-mmpeg

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, metadata, fluent, id3v2

Currently I am using fluent-ffmpeg to convert a video into an mp3 file and add metadata.

I am adding the title and artist like this:

```
.withAudioCodec('libmp3lame')
.toFormat('mp3')
.outputOptions('-id3v2_version', '4')
.outputOptions('-metadata', 'title=' + songTitle)
.outputOptions('-metadata', 'artist=' + songArtist)
```

I would also like to add album art. I am looking to do something like one of these options:

```
.outputOptions('-metadata', 'title=' + songTitle)
.outputOptions('-metadata', 'artist=' + songArtist)
.outputOptions('-metadata', 'albumArt=' + base64image)
```

or

```
.outputOptions('-metadata', 'title=' + songTitle)
.outputOptions('-metadata', 'artist=' + songArtist)
.outputOptions('-metadata', 'albumArt=' + pathToImage)
```

How do I add the album art to the mp3 file?

Comment: I don't have an answer, yet, I was just working on something really similar over at a side project I'm developing called "Unmix". This is my latest progress: https://github.com/unmix/unmix/blob/feat/id3v2/app/services/id3v2_tagger.rb#L50

Comment: @EladG did you ever figure this out?

Comment: no I do think I figured it out. I would reach out to the ffmpeg people for help